# Rails 4 ActiveRecord: Order recrods by attribute and association if it exists

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have three models that I am having trouble ordering:

```
User(:id, :name, :email)
Capsule(:id, :name)
Outfit(:id, :name, :capsule_id, :likes_count)
Like(:id, :outfit_id, :user_id)
```

I want to get all the `Outfits` that belong to a `Capsule` and order them by the `likes_count`.
This is fairly trivial and I can get them like this:

`Outfit.where(capsule_id: capsule.id).includes(:likes).order(likes_count: :desc)`

However, I then want to also order the outfits so that if a given user has liked it, it appears higher in the list.

Example if I have the following outfit records:

```
Outfit(id: 1, capsule_id: 2, likes_count: 1)
Outfit(id: 2, capsule_id: 2, likes_count: 2)
Outfit(id: 3, capsule_id: 2, likes_count: 2)
```

And the given user has only liked outfit with id 3, the returned order should be IDs: `3, 2, 1`

I'm sure this is fairly easy, but I can't seem to get it. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Postgres SQL with a subquery

```
SELECT outfits.* 
FROM outfits 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT likes.outfit_id, 1 AS weight 
                 FROM likes 
                 WHERE likes.user_id = @user_id) AS user_likes 
ON user_likes.outfit_id = outfits.id 
WHERE outfits.capsule_id = @capsule_id 
ORDER BY user_likes.weight ASC, outfits.likes_count DESC;
```

Postgres gives NULL values bigger weight when ordering. I am not sure how this would look in Arel query. You can try converting it using this [cheatsheets](https://github.com/rstacruz/cheatsheets/blob/master/arel.md).